# The jump function is acting a bit weird and i have no idea what is wrong with it, can someone suggest some things to do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementSpeed = 5f;
    public float jumpForce = 8f;
    public float gravity = -20f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    private CharacterController characterController;
    private Vector3 velocity;

    private bool isGrounded;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked; // Lock the cursor
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Check if grounded
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, 0.1f, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        // Player Movement
        float horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveDirection = transform.right * horizontalMovement + transform.forward * verticalMovement;

        characterController.Move(moveDirection * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Player Jump
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpForce * -2f * gravity);
        }

        // Apply gravity
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        characterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        // Unlock cursor on Escape key press (for testing/debugging purposes)
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None; // Unlock the cursor
        }
    }
}
```

I find myself in a state of slight perplexity regarding the jump mechanic and its apparent malfunction. Despite meticulously scrutinizing the input handling and conducting a thorough troubleshooting process, I remain unable to ascertain the root cause of the issue.

Comment: please update your question to specify what it is doing, a bit funky is not clear what is happening.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.